# When using getElementById getting only null value in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

When i tried to pass value from html to javascript by using getElementById in jsp getting null value.

```
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
             <form method="POST" >
            Name<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" onblur="Auto()"><br>
         Value<input type="text" name="auto">
            </form>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Auto(){

      var name=document.getElementById(name);

      document.write(name);

      }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `name` is a string. Use `"name"` instead.

Comment: you need to pass name within inverted commas.

Comment: when putting like this "name" i got [object HTMLInputElement].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the name in quotes as in `"name"`. Then you have to get the value of what is returned by using `.value`
Otherwise you will get the `[object HTMLInputElement]` displayed

This is working

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST">
    Name<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" onblur="Auto()"><br> Value
    <input type="text" name="auto">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function Auto() {
      var name = document.getElementById("name").value
      document.write(name);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned a value to `name` (at the time `getElementById` is evaluated) so it is implicitly `undefined`. (The `var` statement is hoisted so the variable is declared, which means you aren't touching `window.name`).

You don't have any element that matches the string value of that (`"undefined"`), so `getElementById` returns `null`.

You need to use a string literal:

```
var name=document.getElementById("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try access Element by id you need to pass the element's name with comma, here you try to pass a variable.
So try this :

```
 var name=document.getElementById('name');
```

Comment: "comma" — apostrophes are not commas.

Comment: when putting like this "name" i got [object HTMLInputElement].